# Use query builder to get informations from relation table

Tags: php, sql, symfony, query-builder

I have two entity, Annonce and Category with a ManyToMany relationship.
I would like to get the annonce who have the category contained in a array.

In the database i have the following schema:

> Category Table :

[image]

> Annonce table:

[image]

> Annonce_Category table:

[image]

Here is my QueryBuilder :

```
 $qb = $this->createQueryBuilder('a')
                ->select('a')
                ->leftJoin('a.ville', 'v')
                ->leftJoin('MDBAnnonceBundle:Category', 'c', 'WITH', 'c.id = a.id')
        ->where("c.nom IN(:arrayCat)")
        ->setParameter('arrayCat', $arrayCat);

        if ($item != "all") {
            $qb->where($qb->expr()->like('a.titre', ':titre'))
                    ->setParameter('titre', '%' . $item . '%');
        }



        if ($lieu != "all") {
            $qb->andWhere(
                            $qb->expr()->orX(
                                    $qb->expr()->like('v.cp', ':lieu'), $qb->expr()->like('v.nomComplet', ':lieu')
                            )
                    )
                    ->setParameter('lieu', $lieu . '%');
        }

        $qb->distinct()
                ->getQuery()
                ->getResult();
        return $qb->getQuery()->getResult();
```

In $arrayCat i have the name (Category.nom) of each category associated to my annonce like that :

```
array (size=4)
  0 => string 'Voiture' (length=7)
  1 => string 'PC portable' (length=11)
  2 => string 'Accesoires' (length=10)
  3 => string 'Smartphone' (length=10)
```

Here my Entities :

> Annonce.php

```
<?php

    namespace MDB\AnnonceBundle\Entity;

    use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;
    use Doctrine\Common\Collections\ArrayCollection;


    /**
     * Annonce
     *
     * @ORM\Table()
     * @ORM\Entity(repositoryClass="MDB\AnnonceBundle\Entity\AnnonceRepository")
     */
    class Annonce {

        public function __construct() {
            $this->date = new \Datetime();
            $this->categories = new ArrayCollection();
            $this->images= new ArrayCollection();
        }

        /**
         * @var integer
         *
         * @ORM\Column(name="id", type="integer")
         * @ORM\Id
         * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="AUTO")
         */
        private $id;

        /**
         * @var string
         *
         * @ORM\Column(name="titre", type="string", length=255)
         */
        private $titre;

        /**
         * @var string
         *
         * @ORM\Column(name="description", type="text")
         */
        private $description;

        /**
         * @ORM\Column(name="date", type="date")
         */
        private $date;

        /**
         * @var float
         *
         * @ORM\Column(name="prix", type="float")
         */
        private $prix;

        /**
         * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="MDB\AdresseBundle\Entity\Ville", inversedBy="annonces")
         * 
         */
        private $ville;

        /**
         * @ORM\ManyToMany(targetEntity="MDB\AnnonceBundle\Entity\Category", cascade={"persist"})
         */
        private $categories;

        /**
         * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="MDB\AnnonceBundle\Entity\AdvertType", inversedBy="annonces")
         * 
         */
        private $advertType;

        /**
         * @ORM\ManyToMany(targetEntity="MDB\UserBundle\Entity\User")
         *
         */
        private $wishlist;

        /**
         * @var boolean
         *
         * @ORM\Column(name="telAppear", type="boolean")
         */
        private $telAppear;

        /**
       * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="MDB\UserBundle\Entity\User", inversedBy="annonces")
       * @ORM\JoinColumn(nullable=false)
       */
      private $user;

        /**
         * @ORM\OneToMany(targetEntity="MDB\PlatformBundle\Entity\Image", mappedBy="annonce" , cascade={"persist"} )
         */
        private $images;

        /**
         * Get id
         *
         * @return integer 
         */
        public function getId() {
            return $this->id;
        }

        /**
         * Set titre
         *
         * @param string $titre
         * @return Annonce
         */
        public function setTitre($titre) {
            $this->titre = $titre;

            return $this;
        }

        /**
         * Get titre
         *
         * @return string 
         */
        public function getTitre() {
            return $this->titre;
        }

        /**
         * Set description
         *
         * @param string $description
         * @return Annonce
         */
        public function setDescription($description) {
            $this->description = $description;

            return $this;
        }

        /**
         * Get description
         *
         * @return string 
         */
        public function getDescription() {
            return $this->description;
        }

        /**
         * Set prix
         *
         * @param float $prix
         * @return Annonce
         */
        public function setPrix($prix) {
            $this->prix = $prix;

            return $this;
        }

        /**
         * Get prix
         *
         * @return float 
         */
        public function getPrix() {
            return $this->prix;
        }


        public function addCategory(Category $category) {
            // Ici, on utilise l'ArrayCollection vraiment comme un tableau
            $this->categories[] = $category;

            return $this;
        }

        public function removeCategory(Category $category) {
            $this->categories->removeElement($category);
        }

        public function getCategories() {
            return $this->categories;
        }

        public function getDate() {
            return $this->date;
        }

        public function setDate($date) {
            $this->date = $date;
        }

        public function getWishlist() {
            return $this->wishlist;
        }

        public function setWishlist($wishlist) {
            $this->wishlist = $wishlist;
        }

        public function getVille() {
            return $this->ville;
        }

        public function setVille($ville) {
            $this->ville = $ville;
        }

        public function getTelAppear() {
            return $this->telAppear;
        }

        public function setTelAppear($telAppear) {
            $this->telAppear = $telAppear;
        }

        public function getUser() {
            return $this->user;
        }

        public function setUser($user) {
            $this->user = $user;
        }

        public function addImage(\MDB\PlatformBundle\Entity\Image $image) {
            $this->images[] = $image;
            $image->upload();
            return $this;
        }

        public function removeImage(\MDB\PlatformBundle\Entity\Image $image) {
            $this->images->removeElement($image);
        }

        public function getImages() {
            return $this->images;
        }

        public function getAdvertType() {
            return $this->advertType;
        }

        public function setAdvertType($advertType) {
            $this->advertType = $advertType;
        }

    public function getFirstImage(){
        return $this->images[0];
    }

    }
```

> Category.php

```
<?php

namespace MDB\AnnonceBundle\Entity;

use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;

/**
 * Category
 *
 * @ORM\Table()
 * @ORM\Entity
 */
class Category
{
    /**
     * @var integer
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="id", type="integer")
     * @ORM\Id
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="AUTO")
     */
    private $id;

    /**
     * @var string
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="nom", type="string", length=255)
     */
    private $nom;

    /**
     * @var string
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="appartenance", type="string", length=255)
     */
    private $appartenance;


    /**
     * Get id
     *
     * @return integer 
     */
    public function getId()
    {
        return $this->id;
    }

    /**
     * Set nom
     *
     * @param string $nom
     * @return Category
     */
    public function setNom($nom)
    {
        $this->nom = $nom;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Get nom
     *
     * @return string 
     */
    public function getNom()
    {
        return $this->nom;
    }

    public function getAppartenance() {
        return $this->appartenance;
    }

    public function setAppartenance($appartenance) {
        $this->appartenance = $appartenance;
    }


}
```

So how can i add the clause to get all of the annonces who have the category contained in the arrayCat.

**EDIT**

```
$arrayCat = explode(",", $categorie);


        $qb = $this->createQueryBuilder('a')
                ->select('a')
                ->leftJoin('a.ville', 'v')
                ->innerJoin('MDBAnnonceBundle:Category', 'c', 'WITH', 'c.id = a.id')
        ->where("c.nom IN(:cat)")
        ->setParameter('cat', $arrayCat);

        if ($item != "all") {
            $qb->andWhere($qb->expr()->like('a.titre', ':titre'))
                    ->setParameter('titre', '%' . $item . '%');
        }



        if ($lieu != "all") {
            $qb->andWhere(
                            $qb->expr()->orX(
                                    $qb->expr()->like('v.cp', ':lieu'), $qb->expr()->like('v.nomComplet', ':lieu')
                            )
                    )
                    ->setParameter('lieu', $lieu . '%');
        }

        $qb->distinct()
                ->getQuery()
                ->getResult();
        return $qb->getQuery()->getResult();
```

But i still have no result

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe change

```
->leftJoin('MDBAnnonceBundle:Category', 'c', 'WITH', 'c.id = a.id')
```

to

```
->innerJoin('a.categories', 'c')
```

because you fetch all the annonces regardless of their category...

Comment: are you sur about this line ? it's capitalized ?   ->Where("c.nom IN(:followeeIds)")

Comment: Wht do you mean by capitalized ? Upper case ? (sorry English is not my mother tongue). No i'm not sure even if i can check existence like that

Comment: english is not my mother tongue too :) the probleme is ->Where instead of ->where should give you an error

Comment: True, but i don't have any error. I tried with 'where' but still the same thing

Comment: try to remove the with clause :   ->innerJoin('MDBAnnonceBundle:Category', 'c', 'WITH', 'c.id = a.id') and let doctrine handle it directly. because a.id = c.id make no-sens i think.

Comment: `[Semantical Error] line 0, col 84 near 'c.nom in(:cat)': Error: 'c' is not defined`. And this normal.

Comment: sorry i mean ->innerJoin('MDBAnnonceBundle:Category', 'c', 'WITH', 'c.id = a.id') to ->innerJoin('a.categories', 'c')

Comment: It's working. Thank you , i edited your answer as the correct one :)